# An array is monotonic if it is either monotone increasing or monotone decreasing

Tags: java, arrays, vector

```
class Solution {

    public boolean isMonotonic(int[] A) 
    {
        
        boolean increasing = true;
        boolean decreasing = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; ++i) 
        {
            
            if (A[i] > A[i+1])
                increasing = false;
            
            if (A[i] < A[i+1])
                decreasing = false;

        }

        return increasing || decreasing;

     }

}
```

Can anyone please explain how the return value is working.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the superfluous `'`, because the question text suggests you don't care about the compile errors caused by them. If I was wrong, feel free to revert my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`increasing || decreasing` means `increasing OR decreasing`. If either variable is `true` then the whole method will return `true`, otherwise it will return `false`.

`||` is the [logical OR operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

So, the return value is an example of functional programming `||` is working as if condition.

```
return increasing || decreasing;
```

abobe line is similar to

```
 if (increasing || decreasing)
     return true;
 else 
    return false
```

Comment: No, it is acting as the logical or operator.

Comment: You are *using* `||` in your code that's supposed to demonstrate what `||` does, that seems recursive.

Answer (score 0):

it will return true if one of them or both is true.
False if both are false.